# What's the point of tmpfile when saving numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking up in Numpy docs how to save an array, the provided this:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
outfile = TemporaryFile()
np.save(outfile, array)
```

I tried doing it without the tempfile thing and it worked, so, I'm wondering what's the point of that?

Comment: That's in a `docstring` which test code can actually run.  `tempfile` puts the test file in a place where it doesn't do any harm or clutter someone's disk.

Comment: @hpaulj so you recommend using it?

Comment: have you tried this? `np.save('filename.npy', arr)` perhaps i don't understand the question

Comment: @AlexDeft no, it's for the docstring, which actually gets run, they are called doctests. its so the doctest doesn't harm your computer. the whole point is that you can't access the temporary file.

Comment: @Mehdi Exactly. I tried that one.

Comment: Why are you using `save`?  Just to test and throw away the result?  Or to save something that you want to load later.  This is just like saving any other file.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm saving cause these arrays are the preprocessed data to my neural net. I don't want to do the preprocessing evrre time.

Comment: This tempfile business is distracting you from the important stuff.  It's not relevant to your task.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Many thanks.